# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript

Только начал изучать `js`. Решил  писать 2048 (для поднятия скила), столкнулся с проблемой. Решил протестировать функцию, которая рандомно заполняет и рисует текущее состояние. Вызываю функции при нажатии на стрелки. При первом нажатии всё работает нормально, но при втором браузер виснет и пишет -

> Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

```js
var size = 4;
var counter = 0;
var matrix = [];
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  matrix[i] = []
}

for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    matrix[i][j] = 0;
  }
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function get_number(matr) {
  var tmpRow = getRandomInt(0, 3);
  var tmpCol = getRandomInt(0, 3);

  while (true) {
    if (matr[tmpRow][tmpRow] === 0) {
      matr[tmpRow][tmpRow] = 2;
      break;
    }
  }

}

function drawFields(matr) {
  get_number(matr);
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      if (matr[i][j] !== 0) {
        var tmpField = document.getElementById("e" + counter);
        tmpField.innerHTML = matr[i][j];
      }
      counter++;
    }
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  function handler(event) {

    var KEY_CODE = {
      LEFT: 37,
      UP: 38,
      RIGHT: 39,
      DOWN: 40
    };
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case KEY_CODE.LEFT:
        alert(1);
        break;
      case KEY_CODE.UP:
        alert(2);
        break;
      case KEY_CODE.RIGHT:
        alert(3);
        break;
      case KEY_CODE.DOWN:
        drawFields(matrix);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('keydown', handler, false);
}
```

```css
'#elements
 {
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  right: 400px;
  background-color: #BBADA0;
  width: 465px;
  height: 465px;
}

.fields {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 107px;
  height: 107px;
  margin: 4px;
  border-color: #BBADA0;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  color: #776E65;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #eee4da;
  line-height: 107px;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div id="elements">

  <div id="e0" class="fields"></div>
  <div id="e1" class="fields"></div>
  <div id="e2" class="fields"></div>
  <div id="e3" class="fields"></div>

  <div id="e4" class="fields"></div>
  <div id="e5" class="fields"></div>
  <div id="e6" class="fields"></div>
  <div id="e7" class="fields"></div>

  <div id="e8" class="fields"></div>
  <div id="e9" class="fields"></div>
  <div id="e10" class="fields"></div>
  <div id="e11" class="fields"></div>

  <div id="e12" class="fields"></div>
  <div id="e13" class="fields"></div>
  <div id="e14" class="fields"></div>
  <div id="e15" class="fields"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Reset `counter` back to 0 at the end of `drawFields`.

Comment: same problem(,but now i can make 2 iteration.But thanks.

Comment: ну вот, теперь программа работает в два раза лучше чем раньше. В чем дело - понятно?

Comment: решил проблему ,у меня было зацикливание.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var tmpField=document.getElementById("e"+counter);
> tmpField.innerHTML=matr[i][j];
> ```

Элемент с каким-то из id не существует.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй Объявить переменную в отдельной функции и эту функцию вызови перед использованием переменной:

```
function varCounter(){
    var counter =0;
}


varCounter();
  /код с использованием этой переменной...
```